# Angular 2+ TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, magnific-popup

I cannot find anywhere for magnific popup in angular
the problem is magnificPopup is not recognized by jquery

for comparison, i used jquery-confirm and it works. the process is the same like magnific popup the only different is the calling method which is `$.confirm({jquery-confirm stuff})`

angular-cli.json

```
...    
"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            "../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
...
```

package.json

```
...
  "googleapis": "19.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
    "magnific-popup": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
...
```

Ts

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
...
setTimeout(()=>{
            $(document).ready(function($){
                alert();
                $('.popupImage').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'image'
                    // other options
                    ,
                });
            });

        },2000)
```

Comment: Based on the error it seems like `jquery` is loaded but `magnific-popup` is not.

Comment: No. Stop right here. Do NOT use Angular and jQuery together. EVER. jQuery has no idea what Angular is generating in the DOM, and Angular has no idea what jQuery is doing. Use Angular OR jQuery, not both together.

Comment: @JeremyThille - I disagree (in this case). This particular [tool](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) is a UI tool to open an image and it has a dependency on jquery. I do not see a problem with this. If the question was about DOM or data manipulation I would agree with you.

Comment: Comment about your code: Do not use `$(document).ready(`, instead use the angular [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Comment: @Igor this particular tool is a jQuery plugin. It requires jQuery, which means it is not supposed to be used in an Angular application. I stand my ground. The same tool/functionality probably already exists as an Angular module, and if it does not, it must be custom made. But _no jQuery_. jQuery and Angular are antagonists, strangers to each other, which makes clumsy and unmaintainable code, not to mention you have to load two libraries instead of one.

Comment: @JeremyThille I agree that when utilizing a framework like Angular, it is a good idea to try to avoid jQuery libraries, if possible, as it can add unnecessary bloat to the project. In reality, the jQuery landscape is very big, robust and familiar to most front-end developers. We don't always have the time/skills/energy to reinvent the wheel. It is good to be able to utilize these libraries in these instances. These two libraries aren't antagonists, though there is a lot of overlap in their DOM access and manipulation capabilities.

Comment: Did you restart ng serve after adding the scripts to angular- cli.json file?

Comment: @JeremyThille sometimes you must put aside your perfect programing idealism in real world developing. should make things easier. its good plugin.
beside, i also put document.ready in Angular Lifecycle hook ngAfterViewInit

Comment: @David yes ofcourse

Comment: `real world developing` What do you think I'm doing all day? Knitting? Ok then, well, keep on loading two libraries that have no idea what the other is doing, and good luck :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get this to work, I utilized the following steps:

I created a new project with the cli `ng new ng-magnific-popup`
 I ran `npm install --save jquery magnific-popup`
 I updated `app.component.html` to

```
`<a #img href="assets/BingWallpaper-2018-03-23.jpg">img</a>`
```

I updated `app.component.ts` to

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'magnific-popup';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('img') imgElement: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    $(this.imgElement.nativeElement).magnificPopup({ type: 'image' });
  }
}
```

I also updated the `.angular-cli.json` file to include their css file by adding `"../node_modules/magnific-popup/dist/magnific-popup.css"` to the styles array.

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-magnific-popup) with full code.

Comment: i'll mark it as solution because it answers the question. using the native element is the answer :D
but using viewchild for every img is not practical rather than using class selector.. what if the img tag is dynamic? ie. gallery photos.

just for reference, im using fancybox instead now.. it has npm, search fancybox npm.. and doenst have any problem. its good

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import 'magnificPopup'; // <=== if it exist into your node_module folder
```

Otherwise, import it into your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

thank you peinearydevelopment!.  however for me AfterViewChecked worked, for some reason AfterViewInit didn't.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked  } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'magnific-popup';


@Component({templateUrl: 'home.component.html'})
export class HomeComponent implements AfterViewChecked   {
    @ViewChild('img')   imgElement:ElementRef; 
    @ViewChild('video') videoElement:ElementRef; 

    ngAfterViewChecked (): void {
   
        if (this.imgElement) {
           $(this.imgElement.nativeElement).magnificPopup({ type: 'image' });
        }

        if (this.videoElement) {
            $(this.videoElement.nativeElement).magnificPopup({ type: 'iframe' });
         }
 
    }  
}
```